# UDP Sockets in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, datagram

If `socket.ReceiveFrom (byte [] message, EndPoint endPoint)` is used to receive data on a binded UDP socket, and no data is received what happens? Does it keep waiting for data to arrive or does it continue? I am specifically talking about UDP Datagrams.

Comment: There is a timeout option: `Socket.ReceiveTimeout`, example:             `socket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;`

Comment: @M.Babcock Thanks for answering. So I need to basically set the receive timeout - if it surpasses the timeout it automatically moves on? Is that correct? And are you sure this applies to UDP sockets too?

Comment: No if the timeout expires an exception is raised which you will need to handle. I experienced packet loss when using the socket async (which was probably caused by the intensive work I did on receive) so in my situation I had to implement a timeout and handle the request synchronously with a timeout to kill the listening thread. Your mileage my vary.

Comment: Are yous sure this applies to UDP sockets? Because you said "receive" which is TCP not UDP.

This is what I am basically doing: I listen for information for 10 seconds. If I get information I call function a, but if I don't I call function b. Do you have any idea how I would do this? Would I just set ReceiveTimeout to 10 seconds and then call ReceiveFrom()?

Comment: Receive applies to both TCP and UDP, it is the connections that are lost when using UDP.

Comment: Got it. But is what I suggested in my previous comment correct? Set ReceiveTimeout to 10 seconds and then call receiveFrom which will then automatically terminate after 10 seconds?

Comment: Yes, if you set the timeout it will automatically cancel the listen after 10 seconds if `socket.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Could you post your comment as an answer so I can select it as best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to force your socket to stop listening after X number of seconds so you can do something else (such as checking if the application is shutting down) and you are using synchronous sockets then I would recommend setting the `Socket.ReceiveTimeout` to X number of seconds (times 1000 since `Socket.ReceiveTimeout` is in milliseconds) and then catch the resulting exception that is raised on timeout.

Answer (score 2):

It will wait for data. If this behavior is not good enough, you can use the async recieve. Also use the UDPClient. There is no need to roll with Socket itself.

> If no data is available for reading, the ReceiveFrom method will block until data is available

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa329728%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: -1: Without understanding what they are after how can you recommend `UDPClient`? There absolutely are situations where it makes sense to roll your own `Socket`.

Comment: I'm not saying use UDPClient for everything. It's better then hand wiring UDP with Socket if that all you needed.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout.aspx: `This option applies to synchronous Receive calls only. If the time-out period is exceeded, the Receive method will throw a SocketException.` So regardless your answer is incorrect.

Comment: No that is only for Recieve - TCP sockets only. I don't think the timeout will affect RecieveFrom.

Comment: Herp I specifically need to use sockets, because a UDPClient does not provide me enough control over the program.

Comment: @Herp you said the ReceiveFrom method is blocking so If I change "blocking" on the socket to false will it work properly?

Comment: Well then I recommend RecieveFromAsync as the non-blocking option.